# Geometric series with product of binomial coefficents

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, geometric-series, summation-method

I'm struggling with the following summation
$$F(x)=\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\infty}\binom{-5/2}{2t}\binom{2t}{t-1}x^{t}$$
I have tried to look for ways to reduce the product of the binomial coefficient to no avail.

Any hints or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $(n)_k$ denote the "falling factorial" variant of the Pochhammer symbol, i.e. $(n)_k = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$. Then using the definition of generalized binomial coefficients, 

$$S = \binom{-5/2}{2t}\binom{2t}{t-1} = \frac{(-5/2)_{2t}}{(2t)!} \cdot \frac{(2t)!}{(t-1)!(2t-(t-1))!}$$

From here, simplification results, and using the definition of the factorial we can get a couple of equivalent forms:

$$S = \frac{(-5/2)_{2t}}{(t-1)!(t+1)!} = \frac{(-5/2)_{2t}}{[(t-1)!]^2 \cdot t(t+1)}$$

It's not much, but perhaps it's a start?

Comment: It might help if we had more of an idea as to what sort of simplification you want, or what you're using this for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  Ideally I'm hoping for a closed-form formula as a function of x.  The summation comes about in a bigger problem where I'm trying to determine Fourier series coefficients,

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo here?  As it stands, the sum diverges unless $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo.  Now corrected.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-5%2F2+choose+2t%29*%282t+choose+t-1%29*x%5Et+from+1+to+infinity) is anything to go by, the best we can likely do is write it in terms of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series), which can at least be [efficiently computed](http://fredrikj.net/math/hypgeom.pdf). We'll use Wikipedia's notation from their treatement of the hypergeometric series, with $(q)_n$ the [rising Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) (although unfortunately, in their article about the symbol this instead denotes the *falling* one). Write $t=k+1$ so $F=\frac{35x}{8}G$ with$$G:=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{\frac{8}{35}\left(-\frac52\right)!}{k!(k+2)!\left(-\frac92-2k\right)!}x^k=\sum_k\frac{\left(\frac94\right)_k\left(\frac{11}{4}\right)_k}{(3)_k}\frac{(4x)^k}{k!}={}_2F_1\left(\frac94,\,\frac{11}{4};\,3;\,4x\right).$$In particular, $(k+2)!=2(3)_k$ and$$\begin{align}\frac{\frac{4}{35}\left(-\frac52\right)!}{\left(-\frac92-2k\right)!}&=\frac{\left(-\frac92\right)!}{\left(-\frac92-2k\right)!}\\&=\prod_{j=0}^{2k-1}(\tfrac92+j)\\&=4^k\prod_{j=0}^{2k-1}(\tfrac94+\tfrac{j}{2})\\&=4^k\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\tfrac94+j)\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\tfrac{11}{4}+j)\\&=4^k(\tfrac94)_k(\tfrac{11}{4})_k.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for quick solution (and links)!  I was thinking the same thing but hoped someone might know a trick to handle the binomial coefficient product.  Oh well, at least it's framed in terms of a well known function.